# Waiting for store to long and Gateway Timeout (504)

Tags: timeout, nopcommerce

I have a problem with NOPCommerce 4.2. Sometimes, my site opens quickly but it often takes a long time to open with "waiting for ..." message in browser and finally Gateway timeout (Error 504) occurred. I have this problem in both site and admin section. I Uninstall unused plugins and disable unwanted parts. no error log in log section.
Please help me to know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you please share your website link. What is the server configuration?

Comment: thanks for reply. http://shop-origami.ir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My site was very slow with out SSL but after install certificate and enable SSL, problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The site is loading fast. You can make sure bellow steps

1. All resource string for second language is added properly.
2. Go to Admin==>Setting==>General Settings then uncheck all of Localization section.
3. Check all under the Minification second of the same place.